# Matplotlib FigureCanvas: Correctly plot Quadmesh into axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I use the Qt5 backend for matplotlib and try to embed a plot in a FigureCanvas. Now I have a problem with plotting large matrices with pcolormesh into the figure's axes object. Somehow the resulting QuadMesh does not fill the entire axes but leaves space above and right from the mesh.

[image]

A second problem is that the x-axis labels are not rotated although I call autofmt_xdata(). Here is the relevant code:

```
class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.figure.set_tight_layout(True)
        self.matrix_axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        divider = make_axes_locatable(self.matrix_axes)
        self.color_axes = divider.append_axes("right", size=0.1, pad=0.05)
        self.matrix_axes.hold(False)
        self.color_axes.hold(False)

    def build_connectivity_matrix(self, source_neurons, target_neurons):
        # plot the data,
        # data is a 2d numpy array
        color_mesh = self.matrix_axes.pcolormesh(data, cmap=color_map)
        # add tick labels
        self.matrix_axes.set_yticklabels(labels_y)
        self.matrix_axes.set_xticklabels(labels_x)
        self.figure.autofmt_xdate(rotation=30)  # rotate x axis labels to fit more
        # plot color bar
        colorbar = self.figure.colorbar(color_mesh, cax=self.color_axes, orientation='vertical')

canvas = MyCanvas()
canvas.build_connectivity_matrix()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had trouble with whitespace in this situation as well. Try adding this after doing the color mesh:

```
self.matrix_axes.set_xlim(xmax = data.shape[1])
self.matrix_axes.set_ylim(ymax = data.shape[0])
```

Edit to add x squared's answer:

You can use `self.matrix_axes.set_xticklabels(labels_x, rotation=30)` to set the rotation of the text.

Comment: That did it! Any idea about the other problem with the x labels?

Comment: I found out about the labels. Instead of using the extra call: `self.figure.autofmt_xdate(rotation=30)`, I can add the desired rotation to the set_xticklabels call like this: `self.matrix_axes.set_xticklabels(labels_x, rotation=30)`.
Please add this information in your answer, so that it is complete and I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Interesting. I thought about saying that, but I assumed that if autofmt_xdate didn't work, that wouldn't either. I don't have Qt5, so I couldn't test your code to see what worked and what didn't.

Comment: Well, who even understands matplotlib? :)